# Clonezilla disk check incredibly slow

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla, disk-cloning

I am doing backup of my entire disk to image stored on another HDD connected via USB. Creating images went relatively fast (~700-1000 MB/min) but checking afterwards is slooow:  7MB/min. Which means ~600 hours for just one partition. Is it normal? Can I speed up (or skip) this step?

[image]